# How to give the user the option to crop a picture taken from camera before saving it?

Tags: android, image, crop

I am trying to save profile picture. SO the user is provided options to either take a picture or select from gallery. Right now the clicked/selected picture can be saved as such only.Now before saving the image, I want the user to be provided an option/screen to crop the image.

How can I do this?
Please help.

Comment: Refer this link

https://github.com/ArthurHub/Android-Image-Cropper/wiki/Pick-image-for-cropping-from-Camera-or-Gallery

Answer (score 0):

[JavaCV](https://github.com/bytedeco/sample-projects) better for Android since it exports Java API. It also supports other image processing libraries.

You might lookk at [imageMagic](https://github.com/puelocesar/android-lib-magick) for android

These two have good no of image processing methods available. And have option of crop image too.